# APC UPS will not work with Vista

Tags: windows-vista, battery, ups, apc-powerchute

So I bought an APC UPS BE550G the other day, I plug it in, it works fine, I can unplug it the battery keeps my computer going. Fine. What does not work is the software (or any other software that I have been pointed at online). It tells me that it cannot find the battery (in various different ways).

I have tried apc-fix, apcupsd, and Powerchute 2.11 (installed and then could not see the battery) and 2.2 (mostly installed and then could not find the battery to complete the install). I have plugged it into various USB ports that work (I had to unplug other things to try those ports).

So, the question is this: Has anyone out there gotten any APC UPS software working with Vista Home Premium, and if so, how? Or... should I return it for something that will work? If so, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This APC link for [ES550 shows the PowerChute 2.1.1 for Vista](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BE550G&tab=Software)
But, people have found it [does not work with Vista](http://www.pricespider.com/UPSs/APC-BE550G/reviews/BE550G-r1583005.html).

Then there is [one reference that says](http://www.buy.com/prod/apc-back-ups-es-550va-desktop-ups-550va-330w-3-3-minute-full-load-4-x/q/loc/101/208050456.html)

> Included software allows you to set threshold levels for various actions (hibernate, shut down computer etc.) but Vista and Windows 7 can do this natively through **Power Plan settings**.

This Microsoft [support article might be useful for **Power Plan setting**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935799).

This *Microsoft Windows Vista: Visual QuickStart Guide, Second Edition*
sample chapter, [**Conserving Power**](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1190854&seqNum=16) has step-by-step description.

> A UPS doesn't really have to interact with Windows, but Windows includes built-in support for monitoring that sounds power-failure alerts, displays remaining UPS-battery time, and—if power becomes very low—shuts down the computer automatically. A UPS that plugs into a USB port will install its driver and may come with its own power-management software.

Comment: Well that is annoying... I was curious as to what the software actually did...